# Created new package and imported but Definition not found

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have created a simple parser package called parseLine.
I have it in a package in my project.
In parseLine I have a class called "myParse".
I can import it just fine.
import parseLine.myParse.*;
But when I compile I get an error "1172:Definition parseLine.myParse could not be found.".

This is pretty basic I know but would appreciate any help anyone my be able to offer.

Answer (score 2):

`myParse` is not a package, it is a class, so you are importing it incorrectly.

Basic structure of a package:

```
src / my / package / name / ClassName
```

To import `ClassName`, you would use this:

```
import my.package.name.ClassName;
```

or

```
import my.package.name.*;
```

In `ClassName`, it **must** have the following setup:

```
package my.package.name {
    public class ClassName {
        // class code goes here
    }
}
```

As an additional tip, you should follow standard naming schemes for AS3.

- Package names should be **all** lowercase. Even if it is multiple words. `my.packagename` is proper, whereas `my.packageName` is not.
- Class names should be UppercaseCamelcase. So `ClassName` is proper, whereas `className` and `classname` are not
- All objects, including functions, should be lowercaseCamelcase. So `var someObject` is proper, whereas `var SomeObject` is not (same for `function doSomething() vs function DoSomething()`)
- Constants should be UPPERCASE_UNDERSCORE_SEPARATED. So `const SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE` is proper, whereas `const someConstantValue` is not.

Not using those rules won't break anything, but they are the accepted standards in AS3 which makes your code easier to read and maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time.  I did actually try import parseline.*; and it works fine now.  I will change and start following these standards.  Now my problem is the parsing function I wrote ... always something ... thanks.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as correct to properly close it (select the arrow under the number next to the answer)

Comment: Actually, if you can point me to a nice flex/AS3 csv parser script I would appreciate it.  Need to be able to pick up strings inside quotes that contain commas, and retain the commas in the string.  I am getting all the other data I need from the file.  But the quotes are driving me nuts.

Comment: I've always just built my own, honestly. Sorry.